# Multiple directives asking for new/isolated scope - Angular Material tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm getting this error:

```
Multiple directives [ngController, mdTab (module: material.components.tabs)] asking for new/isolated scope on: <md-tab label="Usuários" ng-controller="AccountCompanySearchController">
```

With the following code:

```
<md-tab label="Usuários" ng-controller="AccountCompanySearchController">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
  </md-content>
</md-tab>
```

That doesn't happen when ng-controller is in the md-content directive. Obviously there is a conflict with md-tab directive. Is there a possible fix for this? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that ng-controller creates an isolated scope. This is mentioned in the official Angular documentation.

Your third party component also creates an isolated scope as they probably require for the component to be able to store variables without polluting your scope data.

The solution is to not put them on the same element. Or better yet do not use ng-controller. Here is dome additional reading as to why not use it https://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html